# 0201 bypass cap on top of 2 vias is ok?

Tags: pcb-design

[image]

I have a PCB so dense, there's nowhere to put a few of the last caps, which have to be under the fpga.

The 0201s can bridge 2 vias, placed on a power and ground the fpga needs.

If I were using 0402s, I'd just put them right there.  With those vias smack dab in the middle.

But the 0201s only reach halfway across the vias on both sides.

If if I put them there, the thermal behavior ought to be fairly similar, so perhaps not a source of tomb stoning.

But the pads would be formed from mask, with the other half of the via extending out.

Can I get away with it?

Comment: Only if you're hand soldering.

Comment: As long as the via is filled and plated? Should not be any issue.

Comment: So why not switch to 0402s? In fact, you can fit 0402 caps "interstitially" in a 1mm BGA grid, putting their pads in the gap in the center of group of four vias, without interfering with the vias at all.

Comment: Trust me, there's no way. It's 14 layers, and not a single place you could put even a 6 mil via with a 16 mil pad.  It has 24 DIMM modules and 6 FPGAs on a motherboard sized pcb.  Wait... Actually that's not quite true.  It's the DIMMs which need the 0201s.  As a result, the bypass caps I  have are type 0201 and it's nice not to have 2 types, for the same sizes.  So you're right I suppose, the 0402s fit better under the fpga, most of the time.  Probably I should just get over having 2 sizes for the same values.